# Invalid Data Exception when using ExcelDataReader

Tags: c#, exceldatareader

I have a program that reads Excel file using ExcelDataReader.dll.
Everything was perfect until I moved the file reading to a new task:

```
Stream output = new MemoryStream();
httpRequest.Files[0].InputStream.CopyToAsync(output);
ImportDataWriter importDatawRiter = new ImportDataWriter(authenticationInfo);
Task.Run(() => importDatawRiter.ImportFile(output));
```

ImportLine Code:

```
public ImportResult ImportFile(Stream fs)
{
        IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(fs);
}
```

Now this line:

```
IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(fs);
```

causes an Exception:

**An exception of type 'System.IO.InvalidDataException' occurred in System.IO.Compression.dll but was not handled in user code**

Message:

**End of Central Directory record could not be found.**

The Exception occurs from the second time I call the function.

What Can Be The Problem?

[image: exception screenshot]

Comment: are you using this on an XLS file, instead of XLSX?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 no. I use first and second time exactly the same file. both times xlsx.

Comment: You aren't `await`ing `.CopyToAsync(output);`. So the code goes when the copy hasn't finished

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto That was the problem. Please Insert your Comment as Answer, I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not waiting for the Copy task to finish, so when you get to read the `MemoryStream`, it is not full (it may even be completely empty), so, change your code to:

```
Stream output = new MemoryStream();
await httpRequest.Files[0].InputStream.CopyToAsync(output);
^^^^^
ImportDataWriter importDatawRiter = new ImportDataWriter(authenticationInfo);
Task.Run(() => importDatawRiter.ImportFile(output));
```

And, unless `ImportFile` is a fire-and-forget action, I'd suggest you to use

```
await Task.Run(() => importDatawRiter.ImportFile(output));
```